# When less then max number of integers is inputted, code does not run

Tags: c, arrays, user-input

For the program, I know that the maximum amount of integers that can be inputted is 100 but they could also enter 2 integers or 3 or so on. but if I enter less then 100 the program just stays waiting for me to enter the full 100.

If tried doing a `while i != '\0'` before the `for` loop and then I tried putting an `if i != '\0'` after `scanf` but neither worked.

```
printf("enter a list of integers ");
for (; i < 100; i++)
if ((scanf("%d", &list[i])) != 1)
{
break;
}
```

Right now the program just runs until 100 integers are entered, but it needs to stop if the user only wants to put in less amount of integers.

Comment: Does the program supply a way for the user to indicate when they're done entering data?

Comment: `scanf` can detect `EOF` if you let it. `if(scanf("%d", &list[i]) != 1) { break; }`. You should always check the return value from `scanf` anyway.

Comment: Your program cannot read you users mind. You have to define some way for the user to tell that program that they've finished entering numbers. Until you've worked out what that is we cannot help you. For instance you could say that the user has to enter all the numbers on one line, then we could show you how to do that. Or you could say the user has to enter how many numbers they want to enter first, then we could show you how to do that. etc. etc.

Comment: You need to give the user a way to exit the loop. For example, if a user enters a non-numerical character, you end the loop. Lookup how to use a conditional construct like an "if" statement.

Comment: i tried if i == '\n' break; so that when they hit enter it ends

Comment: `i` is loop control variable, it's never going to equal `'\n'` (at least not in the way you intend)

Comment: @giuseple why not trying to put it condition inside for loop?

Comment: Did you try @WeatherVane's method?

Comment: Of course, you'll either have to type the EOF key or enter something non-numeric.

Comment: Note: It is always a good idea to check `scanf`'s (or any other function's for that matter) return value to see if it succeeded. Lots of fun things can go wrong and I'm lying. They aren't fun.

Comment: so when i tried weather vane method is still stays waiting for the rest of the input

Comment: What exactly did you enter? Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem. That means it can be copy/pasted, compiled and run exactly as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you change scanf into gets/sscanf, you can stop after entering anything else than a valid integer (newline, letter...).

```
int list[100];
printf("enter a list of integers ");
char tmp[1024];
int i=0;
for (; i < 100; i++) {
    gets(tmp);
    if (sscanf(tmp, "%i", &list[i]) != 1) break;
}
printf("i is %i\n",i)
```